# jsPDF can't get text maxWidth and .splitTextToSize to work

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to get some text to wrap around to the next line ones it goes past a certain point but it doesn't wrap at all

here's my code:

```
     <script>
        function generatePDF() {
            
            
            var name = "Blah";
            var paymentaddress = 'some bullshit, but like a whole lotta bulshit, man, like you know what I mean, man?';
            var date = new Date();
            var totalPrice = 100;
            let day = date.getDate();
            let month = date.getMonth();
            let year = date.getYear();
         
            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            
            pdf.setFont('courier');
            pdf.setFontSize(22);
            pdf.text("Test Order Receipt", 38, 23);
            pdf.setFontSize(12);
            pdf.text("Name: " + name, 20, 40);
            pdf.text("Payment Address: \n" + paymentaddress, 20, 50, {maxWidth: 50, align: 'left'});
            pdf.text("Total: €" + totalPrice + ".00", 20, 95);
            pdf.text("Date: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year, 20, 110);
            pdf.line(15, 30, 200, 30);
            pdf.line(15, 30, 15, 120);
            pdf.line(15, 120, 200, 120);
            pdf.line(200, 120, 200, 30);
            pdf.line(15, 100, 200, 100);
             
            pdf.save('Receipt (' + date + ').pdf');
        }
     </script>
```

I've tried using maxWidth and .splitTextToSize but .splitTextToSize just stops any of the java script working